# How to convert temperature to celcius?

Tags: openweathermap

I am an absolute newbie at openweather. When I tried their examples and was scrolling down the information, the temperature of Melbourne was 297.42. I can confirm it definitely was not so my question is do I have to format the temperature somehow because it is not really conventional (as it is a 3 digit number) and I was thinking it was wrong.

```
{
"temp":297.42,
"feels_like":298.33,
"temp_min":295.91,
"temp_max":299.24,

}
```

above is only a snapshot

Comment: That could be Kelvin, in which case you would subtract 270.something to get Celsius. There is probably a setting for the scale.

Comment: Per the docs the default is indeed Kelvin for temperatures: https://openweathermap.org/current. Subtract 273.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperature in Kelvin is used by default in openweather api. You need to add `?units=metric` to your api call to get Celsius.

> Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units.

```
For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
For temperature in Celsius use units=metric
Temperature in Kelvin is used by default, no need to use units parameter in API call
```

List of all API parameters with units [openweathermap.org/weather-data](http://openweathermap.org/weather-data).
You can specify the format you want returned for the temp. `standard`, `metric`, and `imperial` units are available. http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json&units=metric
or
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json&units=imperial

just pass units are parameter in api.

For conversions -

`Kelvin to Fahrenheit is:`

```
(( kelvinValue - 273.15) * 9/5) + 32
```

`kelvin to celsius:`

```
Just subtract 273.15.
```

Comment: another question, how recent are the temperatures because when I convert them the result is much different to the actual temperature

Comment: I don't think so it would be live because obviously, it's just fetching data from global and local weather models, satellites, radars and a vast network of weather stations. This definitely would need time to update! I tried to search for what's the update time period of openweathermap but unfortunately couldn't find any links for it. However, just to compare, there was information about AERISWEATHER API which updates their data at 15 minutes interval https://www.aerisweather.com/support/kb/api/how-often-does-the-api-data-update/

Comment: Taking a wild guess shot, may be 15mins/30mins/1hr would definitely be their update interval.